# Find Cursor in which input

Tags: javascript

I have two inputs

```
<input id="foo" name="foo"/>
<input id="bar" name="bar"/>
```

How to find cursor present in which input?

I am able to find position of cursor in it, but I need to know in which input cursor exists.

Comment: You tagged it Javascript, but who knows, maybe [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) might do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While other answers give you the current active element. I prefer to provide another answer which give you the exact 'which input' you asked.

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" onfocus="onfocus(this)" onblur="onblur(this)"/>
<input id="bar" name="bar" onfocus="onfocus(this)" onblur="onblur(this)"/>

<script>

var idOfInputFocused = ""; // what you need
function onfocus(input) {
   idOfInputFocused = input.id;
}

function onblur(input) {
   idOfInputFocused = "";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find the element that is currently active/on focus, use

```
document.activeElement
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_document_activeelement.asp

Comment: Just a nitpick: most here seem to prefer MDN over w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

If the element has the cursor, it has the focus, you can find out using `activeElement][1]`.

```
var activeElement = document.activeElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify html, and need to know over which input cursor is positioned you can try such approach

```
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName === "INPUT") {
            console.log(e.target.id);
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = e.target.id;
        }
    });
```

Here you can find more information about events delegation - https://javascript.info/event-delegation, so you can wrap your inputs into some block and set event listener to that wrapper, listen any events on it and figure out what happened inside.

And be sure to remove event listener after necessary actions were performed)
Information about removing event listeners you can find here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp.

link to test this solution https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GB7P6V4ACH1O